# Font awesome replacing hardcoded codes

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

I'm facing a problem with font awesome icons replacing part of string.

I print items names in HTML tree. These items are specified in database. In the tree items names are composed of 3 columns (eg. prefix, first name, last name; so "ABC","John","Doe" = "ABC John Doe").

Now, I want to use prefix as font awesome icon.

example:

```
"\135","John","Doe"
"\137","Nancy","Davolio"
"\135","George","Buchanan"
```

where HTML tree will print:

```
<li>\135 John Doe</li>
<li>\137 Nancy Davolio</li>
<li>\135 George Buchanan</li>
```

My problem is, that I need to replace this code-part of string (\135) with font awesome icon, but I cannot manipulate HTML template, so I can't add classes easily and I also can't use CSS ::before (example [here](https://davidwalsh.name/font-awesome-tags)), because icons are not same. What I can do is adding CSS and JavaScript.

I' out of ideas how to do this in easiest possible way. Only thing that I can think of is finding string in html with javascript and then add a new class to it's parent. But I hope there is easier way.

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Is there a connection between the prefix and an icon?

Comment: Yes, prefix is icon code from Font Awesome codebook.

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: I tried css :before solution from here [link](https://davidwalsh.name/font-awesome-tags) , it was working for me, but that's not what I'm looking for. Now I have no idea how to do it. Because I need to have specified icon code in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a very crude attempt below. This method maps the css content code to the icon class with separate calls, so if you are using all the icons this jQuery is going to get huge. But, except for the last icon in the example, [I couldn't find \635 here](http://seehowsupport.com/font-awesome/), it works:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("li:contains('\\135')").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace("\\135", "<i     class='fa fa-rocket'></i>"); 
  });
  $("li:contains('\\137')").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace("\\137", "<i     class='fa fa-chevron-circle-left'></i>"); 
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>\135 John Doe</li>
<li>\137 Nancy Davolio</li>
<li>\635 George Buchanan</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nathaniel. I'm using just a few icons, so the code won't be huge. This solution is wokring for me, but I will keep this thread open for a while, in case there is better solution. Many thanks!